# mysqli is connecting to database but it is not storing the data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
/*php file*/

<?php
require("DBinfo.inc");

$query= "insert into login (first_name,email,password,picture_path) values ('" . $_GET['first_name'] . "'," . $_GET['email'] . "'," . $_GET['password'] . "'," . $_GET['picture_path'] . "')";  

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

if (!$result){
    $output="{'msg':'fail'}";
}else{
    $output="{'msg':'user is added'}";
}

print($output);
mysqli_close($connect);
?>



/*DBinfo.inc*/
<?php


$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="root";
$database ="twitter";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("Cannot connect to database". mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>



OUTPUT:
{'msg':'fail'}
```

mysqli is connecting to database but it is not storing the data

I am using my own computer as a server and running this line to execute the above file:

```
http://localhost:90/Register.php?first_name=adi&email=a@yagoo.com&password=12345&picture_path=home/u.png
```

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your `.inc` file and then edit your question to include the error. I can immediately see that you aren't putting opening `'` characters for the `email`, `password` and `picture_path values`. It's always a good idea to print your final query so you can see what is being passed to mysql.

Comment: Additionally, use `mysqli_error($connect )` to output any error you may get from the database. And like others have said, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE learn about sql injection and how to protect yourself from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `'` in your sql when setting values.

Change

```
$query= "insert into login (first_name,email,password,picture_path) values ('" . $_GET['first_name'] . "'," . $_GET['email'] . "'," . $_GET['password'] . "'," . $_GET['picture_path'] . "')";
```

to

```
$query= "insert into login (first_name,email,password,picture_path) values ('" . $_GET['first_name'] . "','" . $_GET['email'] . "','" . $_GET['password'] . "','" . $_GET['picture_path'] . "')";
```

In fact,you had better use **[Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)** to set parameters in order to avoid **[Sql Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)**